# How to run a php script with nested javascript from the terminal(Linux)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, linux, cron

I have a few scripts which scrape html data from websites.

I use php to fetch the webpage and then js to extract the information I need, eventually using ajax to send data back to php and eventually to the databse. This all works fine, but I have to open a browser and launch the scripts manually due to the javascript.

Is there a way in which I can run some sort of 'cron' to run this script?

Cheers

Comment: Try to search for 'headless browsers'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use [`node.js`](http://nodejs.org) to run your script, unless you are using browser-specific features (e.g., reference to `document` or `window`).